# SQL Oracle error

Tags: sql, oracle

```
insert into tour_concerts values
('1', to_date('02/08/1974', 'DD/MM/YYYY'), 'Misc Concerts', 'UK'),

insert into tour_concerts values
('2', to_date('01/01/1977', 'DD/MM/YYYY'), 'The Hoople North America Your', 'USA'),

insert into tour_concerts values
('3', to_date('05/09/1971', 'DD/MM/YYYY'), 'Sheer Heart Attack UK tour', 'UK'),

insert into tour_concerts values
('4', to_date('09/02/1972', 'DD/MM/YYYY'), 'Works Japan tour', 'Japan'),

insert into tour_concerts values
('5', to_date('03/10/1975', 'DD/MM/YYYY'), 'Magic Tour', 'UK'),

insert into tour_concerts values
('6', to_date('02/01/1974', 'DD/MM/YYYY'), 'Freddie Mercury Tribute Concert for AIDS Awareness', 'UK');
```

---

```
SQL> @tour_concerts1;
('6', to_date('02/01/1974', 'DD/MM/YYYY'), 'Freddie Mercury Tribu
te Concert for AIDS Awareness', 'UK')
                                       *
```

ERROR at line 2:

> ORA-12899: value too large for column "S3327043"."TOUR_CONCERTS".
>   "TYPE" (actual: 50, maximum: 30)

---

Can someone help me fix this error?

---

OKAY I'VE FIXED IT

Comment: SQL Statements such as INSERT have to be terminated with a semicolon `;`

Answer (score 1):

This error is clearly stating that you're trying to insert a too long varchar value in the 3rd column of the `tour_concerts` table.

You can fix this by:

1. Altering the table's structure to make the column accept more than 30 characters. For instance, 50 is the number of characters of the statement that is failing.

   `alter table tour_concerts modify column_name varchar2(50)`
2. Use the Oracle [`substr`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/olap.111/b28126/dml_functions_2101.htm) function:

   `insert into tour_concerts values ('6', to_date('02/01/1974', 'DD/MM/YYYY'), substr('Freddie Mercury Tribute Concert for AIDS Awareness', 0, 30), 'UK');
3. If these records are inserted thorugh an application via jdbc for instance, trim user input to not exceed your table's maximum sizes.

Answer (score 0):

Error is clear: TOUR_CONCERTS.TYPE field allows 30 chars, no more, and you're trying to insert a longer string.
You have two ways to solve this:

1. Shorten string you're inserting (*Freddie Mercury Tribute Concert for AIDS Awareness* is longer than 30 chars)
2. Change your table definition and set **TOUR_CONCERTS.TYPE** field length to an higher value (say 200?)

Answer (score 0):

Huh.I think you should alter your table.30 is too short.
If your DB is oracle:

```
alter table YOURTABLE alter column 'S3327043' varchar(100)
```

Answer (score -1):

Check [this article](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_ora_12899_value_too_large_for_column.htm) it seems your trying to insert longer value than the field, make the fields bigger than the maximal value you could need.